# If statement to call custom stylesheet

Tags: php, css, wordpress, if-statement, stylesheet

I am looking for a way to use an If statement to call a certain custom style
something like

```
if ( is_page('page-id') ) {
    "line to call stylesheet2.css";
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
if(is_page('page-id')){
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my.css">';
}else {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="another.css">';
}
```

Comment: ok i added this to my functions.php, sorry didnt mention i am using wordpress.
but now i lost my special characters related to my language f.e. ŽĐŠ

Comment: @Nec So does it works for you now or not? (How did you "lost characters" ?)

Comment: it works fine, the stylesheet is being called, but after placing this on the bottom of my function.php , yes the previous tag was closed and i opened a new one for this, the page behaved like i changed UTF-8 to some other language which doesnt contain special letters

Comment: @Nec I can't help you there and this is not related to the code. You have to look how your file is encoded and saved. (If you use Notpad++ you can go to encoding and then choose UTF-8)

Comment: @Nec I can't see where your problem is/ what's not working, so I can't help you.